# Save images of a matplotlib figure at different coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a big figure using matplotlib, and then save a few parts of it at different specific coordinates (so manual zooming after plt.show() is not an option - there is no guarantee I can zoom to some precise coordinates - or is there?). The picture is fairly large, so I don't want to generate it all over again and again, specifying xlim and ylim every time before plotting. Is there any way to change axes limits after the figure is created? And I am not using an ipython console, but I need to use it in a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with using `xlim` and `ylim` here. Take the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(20))
plt.savefig("1.png")

plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.savefig("2.png")

plt.xlim(0,30)
plt.savefig("3.png")
```

Here a diagonal line is plotted, then we zoom into the first half of the line, then we zoom back out. At each stage a new png file is created. There is no need for redrawing here.

Comment: Does it work the same way if I use object-oriented style with `ax = fig.add_subplot(111) ax.set_xlim(1, 10)` for example?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and it looks like it is working! Thank you, I don't know why I thought it should be in any way more complicated. But it won't work if I've run plt.show() while the figure is visible in interactive window, right?

Comment: @Ilya Yes, I don't think it will work after a `plt.show()`. Although if you use `plt.ion()` that may reinstate the same functionality.

Comment: For some reason if I use `plt.ion()` I don't see the figure at all - a grey window appears for half a second and momentarily disappears for some reason... Really weird.